# Google Sheets Query Non-Contiguous Range

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to write a query (inside a formula) that references non-adjacent (discontinuous, discontiguous, I don't know the proper phrase) ranges? For instance: =query(A2:C,E2:F,"Select Col2 where Col5=3")

I want to be able to put my query in Column D, so I wanted to split the range around it.  If I just say "Query(A2:F..." it will detect circular dependency when the equation is in Column D.

If it helps, I have shared a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ORNeprrvlcA2iGULqi1L8kxGSthmhCzTxGpidI2ioeM/) with an example (highlighted in yellow):

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try:

```
=query({A2:C,E2:F},"Select Col2 where Col5=3")
```

or if you don't want the label use:

```
=query({A2:C,E2:F},"Select Col2 where Col5=3 label Col2 ''")
```

Comment: Rock on Ed!  The brackets coerce it to be a single array, I take it.

Comment: If your Local settings uses comma as decimal separator, you have to use '\' (instead of comma, not before comma).

Comment: This answer is totally sane, but it doesn't work for me. The formula is just:
`=QUERY({s1!F1:F12115;s1!AH1:AH12115}, "SELECT Col1,Col2")`. The error is "Nie udało się przeanalizować ciągu zapytania względem 2. parametr funkcji QUERY: NO_COLUMN: Col2"

Answer (score 2):

@Pawel Szczur
Have you tried your formula with "\"?

```
=QUERY({s1!F1:F12115\s1!AH1:AH12115}, "SELECT Col1,Col2")
```

Comment: It works for me, but why does "\" work and not "," or ";"? What's the logic behind it? thanks!

Comment: Maybe locale?   . .