# COUNTIF over multiple non contiguous ranges and with one condition in Google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, merge, count, countif

There's a google sheet with content like this:

```
    | A           |  B       |
------------------------------
 1  | Banana      | Brazil   |
 2  | Banana      | Uruguay  |
 3  | 2022-02-28 by flight   |    // Cell spans over two columns
 4  | Pineapple   | Paraguay |
 5  | Banana      | Brazil   |
 6  | 2022-03-08 by Ship     |    // Cell spans over two columns
 7  | Coconut     | Uruguay  |
 8  | Banana      | Peru     |
```

I need the amount of non "Brazil" entries of certain lines (excluding the combined ones). It should be st like this `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT({B1:B2;B3:B5;B7:B9});"<>Brazil")` which doesn't work. Is there an applicable way without using a series of `COUNTIFS` in which the condition has to be set for every single range?

If this is not possible that way then `QUERY` might be helpful (see [Google Sheets Query Non-Contiguous Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41048968/google-sheets-query-non-contiguous-range)). Then how to obtain the number of the results?

Thank You very much.

Comment: Don't merge cells. It'll come back to bite you.

Comment: @TheMaster  I know. But sometimes we have to deal with the sheets of other ppl.

Comment: You don't even need `INDIRECT` here. `=COUNTIF({B1:B2;B3:B5;B7:B9};"<>Brazil")` will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps you overthinking it:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B; "Brazil")
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B; "<>Brazil"; B:B; "<>")
```

[image]

Comment: Well, that could be a good idea, however I was about counting the NON "Brazil" entries. :-)

Comment: @Robbit answer updated

Comment: Thanks for your support. This will do for now.  So I assume there's no appropriate way to use noncontiguous ranges without expensive ```INDIRECT```?

Comment: @Robbit yes. INDIRECT supports only one range

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need `INDIRECT`: Just  `=COUNTIF({B1:B2;B3:B5;B7:B9},"<>Brazil")` will work.

To create skips, use `FILTER`+`SEQUENCE`.

For eg, This skips row 3 and 6:

```
=LAMBDA(ar,len,COUNTIF(FILTER(ar,SWITCH(SEQUENCE(len),3,0,6,0,1));"<>Brazil"))(B1:B9,ROWS(B1:B9))
```

Or with a named function:

- `SKIP(arr,rows_to_skip)`:

  ```
  =FILTER(arr,
    MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(arr)),
      LAMBDA(n, AND(MAP(rows_to_skip,LAMBDA(s, s<>n))))
    )
  )
  ```

  Then,

  ```
  =COUNTIF(SKIP(B1:B9,{3,4,6}),"<>Brazil")
  ```

  Skips row 3, 4 and 6 in the array `B1:B9`

Comment: Very sophisticated solution. Thank You! I will deal with ```LAMBDA``` soon.